# VS Code - changing tab disables extensions. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Using Visual Studio Code I have installed a few extensions (like Guidelines showing vertical dotted lines between pairs of matching brackets). When I start VS Code I can see all my extensions working fine in the Editor window.

However, when I switch to another tab within VS Code, I no longer see the Guidelines or evidence of any extension working in the new editor tab. Worst of all, when I then switch back to my original tab, all the guidelines etc that were there a few seconds ago are gone!

To fix the issue I have to restart VS Code. This can't be right! Has anyone hit the same problem?

I have tried uninstalling VS Code where it warns me some components could not be uninstalled and I have to do them manually. It doesn't tell me which. When I then reinstall, the extensions are visible (without me reinstalling them) but again I hit the same issues as above.

Please help?

Comment: No idea what could be wrong, but a hint to get a clue what's going on: switch on the Developer Tools in vscode (see Help menu). There is a console tab which might show you errors that happened behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks @MikeLischke.. that's a good pointer that I was not aware of. There are no errors in the Console tab but there are quite a few warnings. The closest related warning I could see was "many messages are being SEND from the extensions host" which made me think there were too many extensions installed... I did uninstall many and actually this solved the problem! Probably some misbehaving extension was causing the issue. Lesson: don't install more extensions than you actually need!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like having too many extensions installed, or perhaps one that is misbehaving behind the scenes, causes this problem. Reduce the number of installed extensions. Use Help->Developer Tools -> Console to see if there are any messages relating to the Extensions server